# I want to assign link Ids to the bus-stops which has particular stop Ids using Java

Tags: java, list, for-loop, hashmap, transport

I have created a list of 28 link ids which are in a sequence of bus-stop numbers and I want to assign those ids to the bus stop with the same id numbers.. I am writing a code like this:

```
//create transitStops
Map<String, Coord> busStopToCoordinate = getStopsCoordinates(); //contains the bus stop ids and coordinate.
for (Map.Entry<String, Coord> entry : busStopToCoordinate.entrySet()) {
            String k = entry.getKey();
            Coord v = entry.getValue();
            TransitStopFacility stop = factory.createTransitStopFacility(Id.create(k, TransitStopFacility.class), v, false);
           

//stopLinkIds
       final List<Id<Link>> stopLinkIdList = List.of(Id.createLinkId("5823673530001f"), Id.createLinkId("5145215680000f"), Id.createLinkId("317565150006f"),
                Id.createLinkId("1504018850006f"), Id.createLinkId("5705260710001f"), Id.createLinkId("317565100018f"), Id.createLinkId("5637147670004f"),
                Id.createLinkId("5606511090002f"), Id.createLinkId("5831437080006f"), Id.createLinkId("6568056490001f"), Id.createLinkId("6888270010007f"), //11
                Id.createLinkId("6140720190001f"), Id.createLinkId("6598332090009f"), Id.createLinkId("6044866480001f"), Id.createLinkId("5637147760010f"), //15
                Id.createLinkId("5418873140000f"), Id.createLinkId("295304080021f"), Id.createLinkId("6866052960004f"), //18-need to edit the link
                Id.createLinkId("5542886270001f"), Id.createLinkId("281215370005f"), Id.createLinkId("5714501110001f"), Id.createLinkId("6036480960000f"), //22-traffic signal
                Id.createLinkId("1504018850002f"), Id.createLinkId("6156254680000f"), Id.createLinkId("317565150042f"), Id.createLinkId("773640050003f"),
                Id.createLinkId("3120319040006f"), Id.createLinkId("1912048840014f"));

        
//adding link ids to the stop. ~ Main Problem

            for (int i = 0; i < stopLinkIdList.size(); i++) {
                stop.setLinkId(stopLinkIdList.get(i));
            }



\\adding stop to the transit schedule
            schedule.addStopFacility(stop);

        }
```

But the last link id is getting added to all the stops. How to rectify this error? I am adding the image of the output, so that one can better understand the question and the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS8gu.png)

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, but note that `TransitStopFacility stop = factory...` is inside the loop, so on every iteration the previously created instances are out of scope and disappeared.  I believe quite a bit of the code that is inside the loop should be outside, before the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I am stuck in the loop part only.  Being a beginner I am not able to figure out, how I will assign all the 28 values from the ``stopLinkIdList`` to the 28 bus stops created using ``TransitStopFacility stop = ......``

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your question:

```
I want to assign those ids to the bus stop with the same id numbers..
```

And to do so you should replace this for loop:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < stopLinkIdList.size(); i++) {
                stop.setLinkId(stopLinkIdList.get(i));
      }
```

by this:

```
  int stopId = stop.id;//fill in the stopId variable accordingly by the id of the bus_stop
  stop.setLinkId(stopLinkIdList.get(stopId-1));
```

and you better define the "stopLinkIdList" list in the beginning of your code instead of inside the foreach loop

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do that? I tried it but I am not able to figure out how to iterate over a list ``stopLinkIdList`` in which id_link are in sequence and assign the values to ``stop`` where id ``k`` is generated at random.

Comment: just to clarify with you, you need the first id_link(5823673530001f) to be assigned to the bus_stop with id=1 and the second  id_link(5145215680000f) to be assigned to the bus_stop with id=2 and so on ... ?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I want.

Comment: It worked.. Thank you so much. Thought the order is bit disturbed.. I will try to rectify that. Thanks again

Comment: glad to hear that, you are welcome, please mark the answer as accepted to close this question, best of luck